# Can you see the voting history of a question / answer

Tags: support, timeline

Bit of idle curiosity here.

I logged in this morning to find that one of my answers had recieved both an upvote and a downvote last night, and it got me thinking.

Is there a way to see the voting history of a post?
In this case, I'd have been able to see if it was upvoted first and someone didn't like that so downvoted it, or if it was the other way round.

I also think it could be interesting from a curiosity point of view, e.g. do the number of votes change at:

- the beginning of a (school) year
- near general deadlines for work / education (e.g. get this finished by Christmas)
- how much more (or less) popular is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/4022608) becoming over time?

Answer (score 23):

You can see the history for **questions**. e.g:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/275144/timeline

Where the number is the id of the question.

This doesn't show the full order of votes because adding timing information would make it possible for people to work out who voted for their question.

The same format works for answers:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/275147/timeline

You need to get the id of the answer. The quickest way to get that is to use the "share" link.

Comment: That doesn't show the order though.

Comment: @Scimonster - the reason for that is because if more information were shown you might be able to work out who voted.

Comment: @Scimonster in the [longer term](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/171172/timeline "my favorite timeline example"), order looks rather less important. Agree it would be interesting to see it though

Comment: what do you mean by "*The same format doesn't work for answers though.*"  I am able to see the timeline for answers...http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/124433/Timeline

Comment: @Malachi - It could well have been the case when I wrote this answer back in 2014. If it works now I'll update the answer.

Comment: it is kind of neat, in the timeline for the question it will show the answer, and give you a link to the timeline for it.

Answer (score 9):

By looking at your reputation changes, you can see whether you got the upvote or downvote first.

[image]

For one post there, the order is UD, while the other is DU.

Comment: The voting timestamp is also accurate when looking at the reputation changes of another user, such as the question's or answer's author.